# Trying to run React Native iOS and android emulators on my windows 10 machine

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, react-native-ios

So I'm trying to run my first React Native project. After downloading React Native, with the expo cli I ran 'npm start' but when I try to run the two different emulators nothing works. I'm prompted to install xcode for the iOS emulator but xcode is exclusively for mac OS. Anyone know of a way for a beginner such as myself to start a react native project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their is currently no way of running xcode on windows, all you can do is create a VM or install hackintosh on your windows laptop, but it won't be running on windows.
Suggestion : You must get an apple system to develop ios apps and both of the other mentioned solutions are only good for learning and not for the production level apps.

Comment: Thank you so much!